# Is it ok to annotate with Hibernate validation annotations both DTO classes and Entities?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

To reduce a chance of a bug. Or should I annotate only DTO?
For example,

```
    public class UserDto {
        @NotNull
        @NotEmpty
        private String firstName;
        
        @NotNull
        @NotEmpty
            private String lastName;
    }

public class User extends AbstractBaseEntity {
        @NotNull
        @NotEmpty
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;
}
```

P.S. Most of the code omitted for brevity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Rest API validation should be in DTO or in entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280355/spring-rest-api-validation-should-be-in-dto-or-in-entity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is completely ok to validate it on both.

Detailed : [Spring Rest API validation should be in DTO or in entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42280355/6572971)