# spring validation with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-security

I have a REST API built with Spring Boot and Spring Security. My question is:

I have a `AuthenticationController` which will have a register and login methods, I want to know where to apply my validation on the entity which will be created as a result of this request. Should I apply it on the `User` class or on the register request? If `User` class, how to apply it in this case?

I added the validation in on the `User` class using Jakarta validation annotations.

Comment: Why don't you apply validation rules on DTO you get from frontend? Also, you can validate data on frontend too.

Comment: That's how I would validate. If you need to validate some logic using that data, I guess you can do it in service.

Answer (score 0):

I would annotate the input requests with Jakarta validations and you annotate the controller with `@Validated` and params with `@Valid`. See here for reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-validation.html

Besides that you can utilize [bean validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/validation/beanvalidation.html) anywhere in your code, for example in service classes. But if your input is already validated, a second invocation of validation would be pointless in this simple case from my pov.

Comment: actually I'm referring to an old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280355/spring-rest-api-validation-should-be-in-dto-or-in-entity => it says that I should apply my validation on both layers. but I didn't understand the reason. also i didn't know how to do it

Comment: Yeah, the accepted answer is valid and correct. Consider this flow:
UserDTO -> UserEntity : I guess in a simple case it should be sufficient if UserDTO is validated.
A more complex case:
OrderStatusUpdateDTO -> triggers changes in OrderEntity and ShippingEntity, the OrderStatusUpdateDTO only has a subset of attributes that change the OrderEntity and ShippingEntity, here you would validate that those entities are in a correct state. You can do in the service layer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-service-layer-validation or builder for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your validation in DTO and then trigger the validation in your endpoint:

```
public class RegisterRequestDTO {
  @NotBlank(message = "Username is required")
  @Size(min = 4, max = 20, message = "Username must be between 4 and 20 characters")
  private String username;

  @NotBlank(message = "Password is required")
  @Size(min = 6, message = "Password must be at least 6 characters")
  private String password;

  @Email(message = "Invalid email address")
  private String email;

  // Getters and setters
}
```

your controller:

```java
@PostMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<?> register(@Valid @RequestBody RegisterRequestDTO 
  registerRequest) {
  // Process registration
}
```

Comment: actually I'm referring to an old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280355/spring-rest-api-validation-should-be-in-dto-or-in-entity => it says that I should apply my validation on both layers. but I didn't understand the reason. also i didn't know how to do it

Comment: actually applying  validating in service is for complexe validation methods that returns true or false ,for exemple the input is a text that is required but also must not have more than 50 chars and must not have certain words also you can add the max size in bites but for DTO its quite simple coonditions